# Curl download file time

Tags: curl

I'm using `Curl` to download files from the ftp-server. Everything works fine except the fact that when I get the file it has got it's remote timestamp. And I want it to have a local timestamp as if it has just been created while downloading. I run this command:

```
curl -v -o "/myFolder/logs/video/flvmux.mp4" "ftp://192.168.26.198/video/flvmux.mp4"
```

Thanx a lot for any help!

UPD: Also, I would like to know why it uses initial timestamp. I mean there is an option --remote-time to use the server time while downloading. Using this option or not gives me the same result. So it doesn't create a new file/ It just copies the existing file with all it's properties(timestamp also). My curl version is 7.35.0

Comment: Just `touch` the file after it has been downloaded?

Comment: Thanx, but I thought that there is a way to do with curl. Touching seems an overhead for me.

Comment: Have you tried    -J ?

Comment: @maio290 I didn't get how it should help me with my problem....thanx for the asnwer

Comment: Was rubbish, didn't read carefully enough. -J would heed the Content-Disposition header, but you're using FTP. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

OK, if `touch` isn't an option for you for some reason, then how about this:

```
curl "ftp://192.168.26.198/video/flvmux.mp4" > "/myFolder/logs/video/flvmux.mp4"
```

Not sure why `curl` tries to preserve the original timestamp even without the `--remote-time` option, I guess there's no way of telling without looking into the code.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I did some research and tested curl on the target machine and it worked as I expected. So I suspect that this behavior is actual only for version 7.35.0, cause on the target machine the version is much higher.